# How to input array of strings with Flask + Swagger UI?

Tags: python, flask, swagger-ui, flask-marshmallow

I have a flask api that automatically validates and generates Swagger documentation thanks to [marshmallow package](https://flask-marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).
One of the API methods is a POST request that wants a specific `id` as a string and a `list_of_ids` as an array of strings. The GUI looks like this:

[image]

Whatever I insert, I always get the same reply:
[image]

So my question is how do you input such list (or array) or strings? Is there an equivalent curl for it?

Comment: Please post your controller code with annotations.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I created some example POST request similar to what you reqested in Postman and here is the result cURL:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:5000/api/v1/add_articles_to_article_list' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "id": "42",
    "list_of_ids": [
        1,
        2
    ]
}'
```